# I need time delay in every loop iteration. Also let me know alternate of bold <b>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is the code for typewriting. After all lines are written, I need them to stay for some seconds and the then disappear for the second loop and so on. Also, let me know what is the alternate of bold `<b>` for making specific words bold as tags do not work with string. They show `<` on display during execution. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

<pre id="typing" </pre>   

<script>

 for (let i=0; i<10; i++) { 
   task(i); 
} 
  
function task(i) { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
      // Add tasks to do 
      var typeString = ['• I \r m Mr.Frits.\n• and I love Pakistan...:)'];
      var i = 0;
      var count = 0
      var selectedText = '';
      var text = '';
      (function type() {
        if (count == typeString.length) {
          count = 0;
        }

        selectedText = typeString[count];
        text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
        document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text.fontsize(6);
        document.getElementById('typing').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
        document.getElementById("typing").style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById("typing").style.fontWeight = "normal";

        if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
          count++;
          i = 0;
        }

        /* SOLUTION : wait two seconds when new line */
        if (typeString[0][i-1] == '\n')  {
          setTimeout(type, 1000);
        } else {
          setTimeout(type, 100);
        }
      }());
  }, 1000);   
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You missed a `>` in the `<pre>` tag. The alternative of `<b>` is `<strong>` (also you can use CSS to bold your contents). Also, `.fontsize()` function is not recommended, as `<font>` tag has been deprecated; use CSS to change font size instead.

Comment: I want specific word to be bold. "<" of  b or strong is shown in the display. I need alternate of making specific word bold.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

<pre id="typing" </pre>   

<script>

 for (let i=0; i<10; i++) { 
   task(i); 
} 
  
function task(i) { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
      // Add tasks to do 
      var typeString = ['• I \r m Mr.Frits.\n• and I love Pakistan...:)'];
      var i = 0;
      var count = 0
      var selectedText = '';
      var text = '';
      (function type() {
        if (count == typeString.length) {
          count = 0;
        }

        selectedText = typeString[count];
        text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
        document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text.fontsize(6);
        document.getElementById('typing').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
        document.getElementById("typing").style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById("typing").style.fontWeight = "normal";

        if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
          count++;
          setTimeout(function(){i = 0;},3000) /*Added this part*/
        }

        /* SOLUTION : wait two seconds when new line */
        if (typeString[0][i-1] == '\n')  {
          setTimeout(type, 100);
        } else {
          setTimeout(type, 100);
        }
      }());
  }, 1000);   
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

alternate of `<b>` is `<strong>`.
you can use css properties to bold your text either. Example:(`font-weight:900;`)

Comment: How to use css on single word. Can you apply this on my code?

Comment: I also run the code. After 6th or 7th loop it starts behaving awkward